# vim match group of numbers and replace

Tags: regex, vim, replace, find, vi

I have a large file with data in this format:

```
regabc123456_user_domain_application_env_id
regdef789101_user_domain_application_env_id
```

in vim I want to do a search and replace ("_" for ", ") and match the machine name (regabc123456).
i am trying this:

```
:%s/^reg.*\{6}_/^reg.*\{6},\ /g
```

^ for beginning of the line 'reg' because all start with this then '.*' for anything after that but before the six digit code starts which I am tryign to catch with {6}.

This doesn't seem to be doing what I want. I can match the machine name, but I can't replace it with what I want. Is there an easier way to identify the machine name with regular expressions? example:

'reg' followed by three lower case letter followed by six numbers followed by an underscore, then replace?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below regex would replace `regabc123456_` to `regabc123456,`

```
:%s/^\(reg.*[0-9]\{6\}\)_/\1,/g
```

**OR**

```
:%s/^\(reg[a-z]\{3\}[0-9]\{6\}\)_/\1,/g
```

If you want a space after the comma then add space after comma in the replacement part.

```
%s/^\(reg[a-z]\{3\}[0-9]\{6\}\)_/\1, /g
```

To match a 6 digit number , you need to use `[0-9]\{6\}`. It repeats the previous token exactly 6 times.

Comment: that works like a charm! Thanks. 
My problem was the () and I didnt' know about the "\1". 
I assume \1 adds back what ever was matched in the first () group? 
btw, it seems that both "\{3\}" and "\{3}" work.